# Argument passed by reference

Tags: javascript, function, reference, arguments

I have the following **JavaScript** function:

```
function insertIntoTable(title, text, sketchFileName, categoryId)
{
    var db = window.openDatabase('xxx', '1.0', 'xxx database', 5*1024*1024);
    db.transaction(
        function (tx) {
            if (sketchFileName == '')
            {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TableXXX (title, content, created, categoryID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', 
                            [title, text, Date.now(), categoryId], 
                            function (transaction, resultSet) {
                                if (resultSet.rowsAffected) {
                                    myNameSpace.returnedId = resultSet.insertId;
                                }
                            }, handleSQLError);
            }
        }, handleSQLError);
    );
}
```

Now I'm using a global variable, `myNameSpace.returnedId`, to get insertId.

Is there any way to add a new parameter to function `insertIntoTable` that references to `myNameSpace.returnedId`?

Comment: why not just call function with myNameSpace as a parameter?

Comment: Because I don't know how it works.

Comment: Huh?? How what works?  Add a parameter to the function - call it myNameSpace or any other name, and just call the function with the object myNameSpace.  You can access and modify any attributes (like returnId) on it then.  (not sure if I'm understanding you, but I added this as an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the variable with two arguments:

```
function insertIntoTable(title, text, sketchFileName, categoryId, nameSpace, variable)
{
    ...
    nameSpace[variable] = resultSet.insertId;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
insertIntoTable( ..., myNameSpace, 'returnedId' );
```

An alternative method is to use a setter function:

```
function insertIntoTable(title, text, sketchFileName, categoryId, setReturnedId)
{
    setReturnedId( resultSet.insertId );

}
```

Call it like this:

```
insertIntoTable( ..., function(value){ myNameSpace.returnedId = value } );
```

Comment: I've used your second option, it is more general and reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to this:

```
function insertIntoTable(title, text, sketchFileName, categoryId, nameSpace) {
...
...
nameSpace.returnedId = resultSet.insertId; // assign this here
```

and call the function via:

```
insertIntoTable(someTitle, someText, someSketchFileName, someCategoryId, myNamespace)
```

You'll be passing in a reference to myNamespace (will be called `nameSpace` within the function).
You'll have access to all of `myNameSpace`'s attributes then (and can assign things to them).